# Excel Sharing sheet with vba and working buttons

Tags: excel, vba, button, locking

I'm trying to share a sheet with a button that open a new window(made in vb) but when I share it the button that guides to another window lock simple doesn't work (yes I unchecked lock), theres something I need to do to share that button and the another window?

The work of this windows is to edit cells.

Here's the code from the window, there's:

```
private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i, a, b, c, d
Dim prio As String
i = CInt(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 17))
a = CInt(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 17))


Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = a
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = Peca.Text
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) = Qt.Text
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4) = ComboBox1.Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5) = Responsavel.Text
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6) = Cliente.Text
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7) = Maquina.Text
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 8) = NumSerie.Text
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9) = Modelo.Text
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10) = Obser.Text



Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 17) = CInt(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 17)) + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 17) = CInt(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 17)) + 1
Peca.Text = ""
Qt.Text = ""
ComboBox1.Value = ""
Responsavel.Text = ""
Cliente.Text = ""
Maquina.Text = ""
NumSerie.Text = ""
Modelo.Text = ""
Obser.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, 15) = Cliente.Text
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, 15) = Maquina.Text
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(13, 15) = NumSerie.Text
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(14, 15) = Modelo.Text
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Cliente.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, 15)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Maquina.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, 15)
NumSerie.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(13, 15)
Modelo.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(14, 15)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sure but how? im new using stackoverflow #edit already found there you go